# CORS error when I upload large file as multipart in ASP.NET Web API 2

Tags: asp.net-web-api, file-upload, asp.net-web-api2, multipartform-data

I am getting CORS (Cross-origin) error when I upload large file, more than 500MBs of size as Multipart data. but, **all working when I upload less than 500MB file and save successfully. Also, my all other POST request is working well.**

I've also enable CORS using nuget package into WebAPI:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors
```

WebAPIConfig.cs:

```
 config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html"));
            var enableCorsAttribute = new EnableCorsAttribute("*",
                                              "Origin, Content-Type, Accept",
                                              "GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS");
            config.EnableCors(enableCorsAttribute);
```

And on top of the controller, I've writter:

```
[EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
```

Error:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:55425/api/MediaUpload'
>   from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy:
>   No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource.

I've increased  `maxRequestLength="30000000"` and `<requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1073741825"/>` as well.

Comment: What’s the HTTP status code of the response?

Comment: Do you find the solution to this issue?

Comment: Yes. I found the solution

Answer (score 0):

Could you try adding the following config under 'system.webServer' section of your client app web.config -

```
<httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
       <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
    </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

thanks

Comment: I tried to add it, but still same issue. I thing nuget package which I have installed does the same. So, I don't need to add anything in Web.Config

Comment: Please check the guideline here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api. Could be some mismatch in your EnableCorsAttribute initialization. You can initially try keeping it simple like -                 

var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");
config.EnableCors(cors);